# PHP parsing JSON response {"errors":[{"message":"msg here","code":34}]}

Tags: php, json

How do I deal with this JSON response?

```
{"errors":[{"message":"msg","code":34}]}
```

Ideally I can do things like:

```
<?php

$response = '{"errors":[{"message":"msg","code":34}]}';

$decode = json_decode($response);

echo $decode->errors->message; // error 'Notice: Trying to get property of non-object'
```

Or, this:

```
<?php

echo $decode->errors['message'] // error 'Notice: Undefined index: message'
```

But that's clearly not the right way.

How do I access the error message?

Comment: `$decode->errors[0]->message` :P

Comment: When you have these kind of problems, try printing out the contents first using `var_dump()` or `print_r()`. The code you're looking for is something like: `print $decode->errors[0]->message;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
echo $decode->errors[0]->message;
```

Because the structure is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [message] => msg
                    [code] => 34
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: [just did that a minute](http://codepad.org/EhAOuLN0) ago :), +1

Comment: @DaveChen see I talked about this behavior in my profile :)

Comment: This is where [FGITW](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/solving-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/) wins. Everyone else (IMO), should delete their answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors object is actually an array with an object inside it. That's what they `[]` indicate.

`echo $decode->errors[0]->message`

This will target the first item in the array which is an error object. You can then access the properties

Answer (score 0):

The decoded object looks like

```
stdClass Object
(
    [errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [message] => msg
                [code] => 34
            )

    )

)
```

so you access it accordingly

```
eco $decode->errors[0]->message
```

To get the first element of the errors array, in case you don't know the ID, use reset.

so

```
$error = reset($decode->errors);
$message = $error->message;
```

or as of php 5.4

```
$message = reset($decode->errors)->message;
```

Sometimes, you're unsure about the structure of the object, here's a nifty little line of code to print objects nicely

```
print '<pre>' . print_r($decode, TRUE) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$decode = json_decode($response,true);
echo $decode['error']['message']
```

Passing a second parameter true to `json_decode` convert the `$decode` to associative array instead of `stdClass` object [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)